# How to install Kubernetes on Ubuntu 2022LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, docker, kubernetes

I installed docker engine using [this page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) successfully. Now I want to add Kubernetes to it but I don't know how?

In Docker-Desktop app that I was using on Windows it was as simple as check out an option in settings, but on Ubuntu I don't know the best way yo do it?

I searched through the internet but couldn't find the right way.

Also I want to know either is it better to install Docker-Desktop that comes with built-in Kubernetes available or install docker engine and something like miniKube separately in terms of speed, bugs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems that you are using Ubuntu, you can install Docker Desktop on Ubuntu using the official documentation:

[Install Docker Desktop on Ubuntu](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/ubuntu/)

You can then use Kubernetes as you were used to with Docker Desktop for Windows.